# How does opcode PUSH0 work in EVM?

Tags: evm, opcode

*PUSH0* is a new opcode that appeared in solidity 0.8.20 to replace *PUSH1 00*.

Q1) Do PUSH0~32 need numbers(data) to be pushed next to it unconditionally?
example : *PUSH1 00* || *PUSH2 05*

Q2) *PUSH0* allocates 0 bytes on the stack. Can specify the number(data) to be allocated next to it?
example : PUSH0 01(is it possible??)

Q3)
What results can PUSH0 produce on EVM? I wonder what it means to allocate 0 bytes on the stack.

Comment: See https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3855  Feel free to post your own answer and I will upvote it like I did with one of your others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opcode is executed by the evm, every number on the stack is a 256-bit (32 byte) number. Small numbers like 5 fit in one byte and can be conveniently put on the stack with `PUSH1 0x5`, reducing the size of your contract code in bytes as opposed to `PUSH32 0x5` (which takes 33 bytes after compiling to bytecode), but both instructions will put the 32-byte number 0x00...005 on the stack. Since you might regard an "empty number" as the number 0, you can conveniently put the 256-bit number "0" on the stack with `PUSH0` instead of `PUSH1 0x0`, using 1 byte instead of the previous 2 bytes in the size of your program and also reducing the amount of gas used.

Q1) PUSH1 and up need a number. `PUSH1 0x5` will compile, but `PUSH1` won't.

Q2) PUSH0 does not allocate 0 bytes on the stack. It allocates 32 bytes, all 0. You cannot specify an argument to PUSH0: `PUSH0 0x0` won't compile.

Q3) See Q2.